# Disable particular dates in Angular Material Date picker

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-material-datetimepicker

I'm trying to us Angular 6 Material datepicker for one of my projects. I need to disable particular dates or give the user an option to choose particular dates(can be some random dates).

```html
<mat-card>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #pickers></mat-datepicker>
    <app-date-picker></app-date-picker>
  </mat-card>
``
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use date validation:

https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#date-validation

So you can use `min` and `max` properties or `matDatepickerFilter` for more specified filters (probably better for your case). You can check two examples in the link above (first `min` and `max`, 2nd with `matDatepickerFilter`).

Comment: Adding a working demo with matDatepickerFilter.
thanks for this, i didn't notice it in material documentation

Comment: Isn't it possible to combine both ? (min max and matDatepickerFilter) so for example you prevent user for navigating from 1 month/year to another.

Answer (score 4):

You can use matDatepickerFilter if required to filter out particular dates.
A simple example will be

`dateFilter = (d: Date) => {
    return [1, 5, 10, 21].indexOf(+d.getDate()) == -1;
  };`

and in template

`<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [matDatepickerFilter]=dateFilter>`

Working demo in stackblitz : [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gs8pjy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-min-max-example.ts)

Answer (score 3):

Probably one of the ways of doing it would be fixing your minimum and maximum dates. So, in your component you set your min and max dates like:

```
 minDate = new Date(2019, 0, 1); //minDate is 1st Jan 2019
 maxDate = new Date(2020, 0, 1); //maxDate is 1st Jan 2020
```

Now in your template:

```
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
   <input matInput [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" [matDatepicker]="picker" 
     placeholder="Choose a date">
   <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
   <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
 </mat-form-field>
```

This will allow the user to select any date between 1st Jan 2019 to 1st Jan 2020 including both the dates. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: hey, in the answer above, how can I put the present date as the maxDate. Please help me out